# Docker container not running

Tags: docker

I have created a docker image which is a python script based on a centos image. This image is working in the host system. Then I converted that image in tar.gz format. After that when I imported that tar.gz file into docker host(in a ubuntu system), it is done properly and the docker images list shows me the image listed in there. Then I tried to run the container in interactive mode using the following command:

```
$docker run -it image_name /bin/bash
```

it throws the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/bin/bash\\\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory\"\n".
```

Although `docker run -it image_name /bin/bash` command is working for all other images in my system. I tried almost all the means, but got no output apart from this error.

Comment: Please update the question to show the exact command line you used to export the image to a tar file, and the exact command line you used to import it on the other host.

Comment: I assume you are issuing a `docker save` to save the image to a `tar` file, then compress using `gzip` and using `docker load` you load the image contained in the `tar.gz`.  I recommend you trying with uncompressed format, just tar.

Comment: Possibly your image does not have bash installed. Try `docker run -it image_name /bin/sh`

Comment: docker run -it image_name /bin/sh also does not work!

Comment: I am also facing same issue. wonder why there are down votes for this question!?!!!

Comment: @Jit how did you get that image? I need to see the dockerfile of the image, or at least I need to see the entrypoint of the image (as you face the problem just with this specific image). please add those info to your question

Answer (score 2):

`docker run -it image_name /bin/sh` works for me! (Docker image, like Alpine, does not have `/bin/bash`).

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into the same issue after updating **Docker For Windows**. It seems that it corrupted some image layers.

I cleared all the cached containers and images by running:

```
docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm -f
docker images -q|xargs docker rmi
```

The last command returned a few errors (some returned images didn't exist anymore).

Then I restarted the service and everything was running again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it got resolved, after following the steps described in this post...
https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1512-export-and-import-a-docker-image-between-nodes

Instead of saving the docker image (I) as .tar and importing, we need to commit the exited container, based on the image (I), as new image (N).
Then save the newly committed image (N) as .tar file, for importing into a new environment.

Hope this helps...